# GenIntellIjRuns is not found in root project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft-fabric

I am trying to modify open source mod for minecraft but getting this error when setting up in cmd ( gradlew.bat genIntellIjruns)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'genIntellIjruns' not found in root project 'In-Game Account Switcher' and its subprojects.
  How to fix it?

I tried to check the task genIntellIjruns in gradlew but there were none. What should i do to set it up?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's pretty much what it says on the tin: there is a reference to "genIntellIjruns" Gradle Task somewhere in your Project, but, apparently, the Task itself might be missing. Can you share the Project you are working on or at least parts of it referring to "genIntellIjruns"?